# How to hide column in ag grid conditionally

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

In columndef we creating columns but we have to hide that column conditionally

```
columndefs
[
    { field: action,
      hide: true ]
}
```

Comment: did you try with `ngIf="!element.hide"`? can you attach your html and ts files to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Hide single column after mount(after "grid-ready"), without full reload:

```
gridOptions.columnApi.hideColumn(colId: any, hide: any)
```

Same with `hideColumns`. If `colId` not defined, `expect(column.colId).to.equal(colDef.field)`.

Or reset `ColumnState` after mount:

```
const savedState = columnApi.getColumnState();
savedState.find(x => x.colId === myColDef.field).hide = true;
columnApi.setColumnState(savedState);
```

Or:

```
gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columndefs)
```

Or bind `columnDefs` with vue/angular/etc, and just update columnDefs.

```
<ag-grid-angular [columnDefs]="columnDefs" ...
<ag-grid-vue :columnDefs="columnDefs" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using gridApi interface and use method setColumnDefs() to achieve it.

```
const columndefs=[{ field:action, hide: true}, [..restfields]]
this.this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(columndefs);
```

Please note you need to provide all column definitions again while setting columndefs you can't do it in isolate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate your columnDef and check which column you need to hide dynamically. Ref below code for same.

```
let obj = this.columndefs.find(
                o => o.field === 'action' // pass this dynamically 'action'
           );
 obj.hide = false; // Set to false

 // After set to false you need to make call setColumnDefs from gridApi
 this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(
      columndefs // pass your columnDef
 );
```

You will get gridApi object, in onGridReady callback provided by aggrid.

```
public onGridReady(params) {
/**
* Function is called when grid is instantiated.
* @param params Ag grid params
*/
this.gridApi = params.api;
this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-alpine" [columnDefs]="columnDefs [gridOptions]="gridOptions" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"></ag-grid-angular>
```